# How do I remove a file with 2 hypens in the name, like --karmic.list

Tags: files, filename

How can I read, write, or delete a file which has a name beginning with a pair of hyphens?

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` there is a set of files whose name starts with `--karmic.list` .

When I try to `rm` or `vim` from the command line, it considers it as argument and reports as unknown arg.

How can I deal with this?  How is it possible to select a file with this kind of name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the full path `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/--whatever` or in the directory `./--whatever`, or use `rm -- --whatever`.